# laravel blade templates minifier using laravel-mix @ laravel 5.4

Tags: minify, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

As of laravel 5.4, they are no longer using gulp but rather webpack, and they no longer use laravel-elixir but rather a new package they called laravel-mix, now I use a package called [laravel-elixir-blade-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-blade-minifier) which minifies laravel-blade templates, how do I use it with now with laravel-mix? I mean, I'm getting confused here.

Answer (score 2):

you can try: https://github.com/hiseanchang/laravel-mix-template-minifier

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-mix-template-minifier



// webpack.mix.js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.minTemplate = require('laravel-mix-template-minifier')

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.minTemplate('storage/framework/views/*.php', 'storage/framework/views/')
}
```

Comment: this method cant minify the inline <scripts>